# PyCharm do the line break in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I studied this problem before writing the post, but I could not overcome it. Pycharm does a line break when displaying a dataframe if it has a large number of columns.

[image]

I've already added line

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 3000)
```

Also I tried

```
df.to_string()
```

It really helps, but all my DataFrames have millions of rows, so it is not a very convenient way. My be there is a setting in PyCharm NOT to do the line wrap?

Comment: it can be function in PyCharm console and it may have nothing to do with pandas - and you can't change it in `pandas` - you should check all settings in PyCharm.